# What Is Website Caching and How to Clear It?

Tags: browser-cache

Can anyone tell me how to fix this.  When I change a product photo on the website, the preview remains the old photo, only if you click on the photo to open it in full size, then the photo is new.  if you clear the browser cache then everything is fine, but I need the website cache to clear so that costumers can see updates.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.
Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have.